# English verb complementation patterns: PCR + DO + object-related pC complex transitive

Tags: verbs, complementation

Is the clause below grammatically correct?

Anyway she’s given us an article for free which is good.

Semantically, its meaning is that a woman gives us a free article.
However, it's verb complementation pattern is PCR + IO + DO, but the verb phrase is PRC + IO + DO + object-related PC.
So, is it grammatically correct?

My question is whether it is possible for a clause that is in a ditransitive construction to have an object-related PC.

Comment: Yes, it's OK, though a comma after "anyway" is preferred. The adjective "free" is related to a predicand, in this case the NP "an article".

Comment: I would put a comma after _free_ too, to make it clear that _which is good_ refers to the situation and not the article.

Comment: Kate is right, the relative clause is a supplementary (non-defining) one, so it should be set off by a comma. Further to my previous comment about the syntactic status of "free", it is not the whole PP "for free" that is predicative but just the adjective "free". As you correctly say, we understand that she has given us a free article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Anyway, she’s [given us an article for free], which is good.*

Preliminary point: your example requires the insertion of two commas, as shown: one after the adjunct "anyway", and one after "free" to set off the supplementary (non-defining) relative clause.

The bracketed VP is a complex transitive one P-Oi-Od-Predicative, but note that it is not the whole PP "for free" that is predicative but just the adjective "free".

As you correctly say, we understand that she has given us a free article.

Comment: Thanks,but my question is whether it is possible that the construction that is PRC + IO + DO has an object complement. Thanks to your first comment, it is clear to me that this construction is possible and grammatically correct.

Comment: @龚诗豪 I confirmed that in my answer when I said that "free" is predicative. Since "free" relates to the Od "an article" (the predicand), you can call it an object-related PC.

Comment: @ BillJ I was thinking for a while, and I think "which is good" is an adjunct that is related to the article.

Its meaning is that, though the article is free, it is good.

Comment: The phrase is so complex. In this case, it can have various meanings. If it relates to the complete clause, adding a comma is suitable.

Comment: Yes, supplementary (non-defining) relatives are a type of adjunct. In your example, the relative clause refers to the whole clause "she’s given us an article for free". As I said in my answer, the relative clause should be set off by a comma. Are you clear about this now?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. By adding a comma, it specifies the meaning of the clause.

Comment: No: adding a comma marks the relative clause as being a supplementary (non-defining) one. It says nothing of the meaning.

Comment: I mean, by adding a comma, it is clear that the adjunct is related to the referent. In this case, it is the whole clause.

Comment: No, it doesn't. All relative clauses refer to something. Defining relatives modify nouns, while non-defining relatives are not modifiers at all, and they can refer to almost anything. That's the difference.

Comment: Yes, in my case, it is possible that the adjunct relates to the article and the whole clause. Because, semantically, she gives us a free article that is good, which is acceptable.

Comment: It is logical that the relative clause refers to the whole clause "she’s given us an article for free". That's what is good

Comment: Yes, by adding a comma, it is more clear for us to see the connection.

Comment: NO; you must stop looking at it that way. A comma marks the relative clause as being a supplementary (non-defining) one. See here: [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining)

Comment: Thank you, My question is clear, and this discussion is beyond my question. I will refer to my reference, Oxford Modern English Grammar.